# Find covariance of estimator and derivative of the log-likelihood function

Tags: statistics, covariance, estimation, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

**Problem:**
Given an estimator $\hat k$. The estimation method is either max likelihood or other method. We know that it's unbiased.
Let $L$ be the likelihood function and $\ell = ln L$.
**Find $\Bbb Cov( \frac{d \ell}{d k},\hat k)$**

**My attempt:**
$$\Bbb Cov( \frac{d \ell}{d k},\hat k) = E( \frac{d \ell}{d k} \cdot \hat k) - E( \frac{d \ell}{d k}) \cdot E( \hat k)$$

As unbiased $E( \hat k) = k$. Also,  $\frac{d \ell}{d k}$ is score function. We know that $E(s(k)) = 0$
Hence, we have

$$E( \frac{d \ell}{d k} \cdot \hat k) - E( \frac{d \ell}{d k}) \cdot E( \hat k) =E( \frac{d \ell}{d k} \cdot \hat k) $$

I decided to take $\hat k$ into the differential.

$$=E( \frac{d \ell  \cdot \hat k}{d k})$$

Since the expectation is linear, I can take the derivative out of it.

$$=  \frac{d E(\ell  \cdot \hat k)}{d k}$$

However, I am still stuck. Am I doing something wrong?
Note. The friend of mine did manage to solve this, so the task has enough information to be solved.

Comment: We have that $\frac{d\mathcal{l}}{dk}(\hat{k}) = g(\hat{k})$ with $g$ is a known function. So, if I understand well, as $\hat{k}$ is not necessarily estimated by maximum likelihood, there is no relationship between $g$ and $\hat{k}$ (otherwise, if $\hat{k}$ is estimated by maximum likelihood, we must have $g(\hat{k}) = 0$). The problem becomes: Calculate $$Cov(g(\hat{k}),\hat{k})$$
More information on $\hat{k}$ and $g$ is needed for this calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But can't we use the fact that this estimator is *unbiased*?

Comment: By the way, I think that $g(\hat k)$ is not necessarily zero for MLE. For example, if we have a uniform distribution, $\frac{dl}{d \hat k}$ never turns zero but always tends to it...

Comment: **If $k$ is the estimator by maximum likelihood**, by definition, $\hat{k} = argmin_k(l(k))$, then $\frac{dl}{dk}(\hat{k}) = 0$. And the information that the estimator is unbiased can't help

Comment: But isn't uniform distribution $U[0, \theta]$ a counter example? $L = (1 / \theta)^n $and $\hat \theta_{ML} = x_{(n)}$.

Comment: Here you find the maximum likelihood method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Principles 
"the necessary conditions for the occurrence of a maximum (or a minimum) are" $\frac{dl}{dk}(k) = 0$. About your counter example, there must be some errors somewhere.
$$$$
PS: in the previous comment, I meant argmax  (and not argmin)

Comment: I don't know if this means anything, but I see another question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4059104/get-covariance-from-log-density-function asked by a different user, about a similar topic, using similarly distinctive notation (e.g., $\mathbb Cov$ and $\mathbb Var$), around the same time as this one.  This seems suspicious to me.  Users are not allowed to have sock puppet or multiple accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all the commentators noted, the likelihood function makes a little sense if your estimator is obtained by, say, the method of moments. I would assume that, in this case, they don't correlate, so the covariance is zero.

Let $\hat k$ be MLE.
As unbiased, let replace the true parameter $k$ in log-likelihood function with $E[\hat k]$. Then, if you swap the derivative and expectation, you will have something like $\ell (\hat k)$. The MLE maximizes the log-likelihood function, consequently, the derivative is zero. The further steps are trivial.