# Get covariance from log-density function

Tags: statistics, derivatives, covariance, log-likelihood, fisher-information

**Problem**
Given a following log-density function
$$ \ln p(y| a, b) = a \cdot g(y) + b \cdot h(y) + k(a,b)$$
where $g(y), h(y), k(a,b)$ are difined function and $a,b$ are parameters.
Find $\Bbb Cov( g(Y), h(Y))$ using $k(a,b)$.

**My try**
I believe that it got something to do with the score function and Fisher information. We basically can calculate the  Fisher information using two methods:

1. $\Bbb Var[(\ln p(y| a, b))'']$
2. $\Bbb -E[(\ln p(y| a, b))']$

These are derivatives.
My idea is to use both of these definitions and to make them equal. Since we have two parameters, I assume that it's a vector case.
Fisher information using (1):
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\Bbb Var( g(Y))\\
\Bbb Var( h(Y))
\end{bmatrix}$$
And Fisher infomration using (2)
$$\begin{bmatrix}
k_a''\\
k_b''
\end{bmatrix}$$
Even though I've found each of the variances, I have them separately and don't know how to get to the covariance.

Comment: I don't know if this means anything, but I see another question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4056593/find-covariance-of-estimator-and-derivative-of-the-log-likelihood-function asked by a different user, about a similar topic, using similarly distinctive notation (e.g., $\mathbb Cov$ and $\mathbb Var$), around the same time as this one.  This seems suspicious to me.  Users are not allowed to have sock puppet or multiple accounts.

Comment: @heropup Actually sock puppet accounts are allowed as long as you don't do anything you couldn't do with one account, like vote for your own posts. Having multiple accounts in and of itself isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I think $\Bbb{Cov}(g(Y),h(Y))$ is calculated (and $\Bbb{Var}(g(Y)), \Bbb{Var}(h(Y))$)

$\Bbb{Var}(g(Y))\\
=\Bbb{Var}(g(Y))+2\cdot0+0\\
=\Bbb{Var}(g(Y))+2\cdot\Bbb{Cov}(g(Y),k'_a)+\Bbb{Var}(k'_a)\\
=\Bbb{Var}(g(Y)+k'_a)\\
=\Bbb{Var}(\partial_a \ln(p(x|a,b))\\
=\Bbb{E}([\partial_a \ln(p(x|a,b)-\Bbb{E}(\partial_a \ln(p(x|a,b))]^2)\\
=\Bbb{E}([\partial_a \ln(p(x|a,b)]^2)-[\Bbb{E}(\partial_a \ln(p(x|a,b)))]^2\\
=\Bbb{E}([\partial_a \ln(p(x|a,b)]^2)-0^2\\
=-\Bbb{E}(\partial^2_a \ln(p(x|a,b))\\
=-\Bbb{E}(k''_a)\\
=-k''_a\\
$

$\Bbb{Var}(h(Y))\\
=\Bbb{Var}(h(Y))+2\cdot0+0\\
=\Bbb{Var}(h(Y))+2\cdot\Bbb{Cov}(h(Y),k'_b)+\Bbb{Var}(k'_b)\\
=\Bbb{Var}(h(Y)+k'_b)\\
=\Bbb{Var}(\partial_b \ln(p(x|a,b))\\
=\Bbb{E}([\partial_b \ln(p(x|a,b)-\Bbb{E}(\partial_b \ln(p(x|a,b))]^2)\\
=\Bbb{E}([\partial_b \ln(p(x|a,b)]^2)-[\Bbb{E}(\partial_b \ln(p(x|a,b)))]^2\\
=\Bbb{E}([\partial_b \ln(p(x|a,b)]^2)-0^2\\
=-\Bbb{E}(\partial^2_b \ln(p(x|a,b))\\
=-\Bbb{E}(k''_b)\\
=-k''_b\\
$

$\Bbb{Cov}(g(Y),h(Y))\\
=\Bbb{Cov}(g(Y),h(Y))+0+0+0\\
=\Bbb{Cov}(g(Y),h(Y))+\Bbb{Cov}(k'_a,h(Y))+\Bbb{Cov}(g(Y),k'_b)+\Bbb{Cov}(k'_a,k'_b)\\
=\Bbb{Cov}(g(Y)+k'_a,h(Y)+k'_b)\\
=\Bbb{Cov}(\partial_a \ln(p(x|a,b),\partial_b \ln(p(x|a,b))\\
=\Bbb{E}([\partial_a \ln(p(x|a,b)-\Bbb{E}(\partial_a \ln(p(x|a,b))][\partial_b \ln(p(x|a,b)-\Bbb{E}(\partial_b \ln(p(x|a,b))])\\
=\Bbb{E}([\partial_a \ln(p(x|a,b)][\partial_b \ln(p(x|a,b)])-\Bbb{E}([\partial_a \ln(p(x|a,b)])\Bbb{E}([\partial_b \ln(p(x|a,b)])\\
=\Bbb{E}([\partial_a \ln(p(x|a,b)][\partial_b \ln(p(x|a,b)])-0\cdot0\\
=-\Bbb{E}(\partial_a\partial_b \ln(p(x|a,b)])\\
=-\Bbb{E}(k''_{ab})\\
=-k''_{ab}
$

Comment: Could you please comment, why $\Bbb{E}([\partial_a \ln(p(x|a,b)][\partial_b \ln(p(x|a,b)]) \implies -\Bbb{E}(\partial_a\partial_b \ln(p(x|a,b)])$ with minus?

Comment: @student yes, is easier looking at double log-derivative and then expand to arrive at the product of the two single log-derivatives (and to use that $-\Bbb{E}(\frac{\partial_a\partial_bp(x|a,b)}{p(x|a,b)})=-\int (\frac{\partial_a\partial_bp(x|a,b)}{p(x|a,b)})p(x|a,b)dx=\partial_a\partial_b\int p(x|a,b)dx=\partial_a\partial_b 1=0$):

Comment: $-\Bbb{E}(\partial_a\partial_b \ln p(x|a,b)])
=-\Bbb{E}(\partial_a(\frac{\partial_bp(x|a,b)}{p(x|a,b)}))
=-\Bbb{E}(\frac{p(x|a,b)\partial_a\partial_bp(x|a,b)-\partial_ap(x|a,b)\partial_bp(x|a,b)}{p(x|a,b)^2})
=-\Bbb{E}(\frac{\partial_a\partial_bp(x|a,b)}{p(x|a,b)}-[\partial_a\ln(p(x|a,b))][\partial_b\ln(p(x|a,b))])
=-\Bbb{E}(\frac{\partial_a\partial_bp(x|a,b)}{p(x|a,b)})+\Bbb E([\partial_a\ln(p(x|a,b))][\partial_b\ln(p(x|a,b))])
=\Bbb{E}([\partial_a \ln(p(x|a,b))][\partial_b \ln(p(x|a,b))])\\$